# Generic methode vs cast

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, casting

I have a methode searching for a winform control by name. My first approche was to do it like that

```
private Control SearchControlByName(Control parent, string name){recursive search...}
```

Calling the methode looks like

```
Label temp = (Label)SearchControlByName(panel1, "label4");
```

Then a thought to myself it would be better do do it with an generic methode like this

```
private T SearchControlByName<T>(Control parent, string name) where T : Control {recursive search}
```

calling like

```
Label temp = SearchControlByName<Label>(panel1, "label4");
```

And now I'm not sure which is the better approach. What are the advantages / drawbacks of the generic method vs casting after calling the method?
In the generic methode I also have to cast the result like this

```
return (T)result
```

Comment: The question is: do you know **at compile-time** which type your control has? If so use generics. Otherwise there´s no point in using generics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there are any disadvantages.

Since there are at least two advantages (see below), I would use the generic version.

- It's prettier (no need for that cast).
- You could use [`OfType<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_OfType__1_System_Collections_IEnumerable_) on [`Control.Controls`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controls?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Controls) inside the implementation (your recursive search) so you don't have to worry about returning a `Label` when the person wants a `PictureBox`. However keep in mind that you can only do that at the bottom level, otherwise you won't go through all the elements of course.